# Linux Mint: Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-38-generic cannot be found

Tags: linux-mint, apt, linux-kernel, initramfs

After several attempts to fix the issue by myself I've decided to post here, basically everytime I'm running an upgrade I received this error message:

```
fabrizio@fabrix ~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.125) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic (4.4.0-38.57) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-38-generic
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-38-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-38-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic
Error! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-38-generic cannot be found at
/lib/modules/4.4.0-38-generic/build or /lib/modules/4.4.0-38-generic/source.
Error! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-38-generic cannot be found at
/lib/modules/4.4.0-38-generic/build or /lib/modules/4.4.0-38-generic/source.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-38-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-38-generic
E: busybox or busybox-static, version 1:1.22.0-17~ or later, is required but not installed
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-38-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.125) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic
E: busybox or busybox-static, version 1:1.22.0-17~ or later, is required but not installed
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to look for similar error and I tried to remove the kernel, to upgrade initramfs and other operations without success, can you point me to right direction?

```
fabrizio@fabrix ~ $ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           759M  9.5M  750M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       286G   25G  248G   9% /
tmpfs           3.8G  9.0M  3.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           759M   32K  759M   1% /run/user/1000
fabrizio@fabrix ~ $ df -i
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             965757    531   965226    1% /dev
tmpfs            970893    813   970080    1% /run
/dev/sda1      19038208 500395 18537813    3% /
tmpfs            970893     30   970863    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            970893      6   970887    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            970893     18   970875    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs            970893     14   970879    1% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs            970893     20   970873    1% /run/user/1000
fabrizio@fabrix ~ $ sudo apt-get install busybox busybox-static
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
busybox-static is already the newest version (1:1.22.0-19ubuntu2).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 busybox : Conflicts: busybox-static but 1:1.22.0-19ubuntu2 is to be installed
 busybox-static : Conflicts: busybox
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic
sudo apt-get -f install
```

see if that solves the problem :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/164573)

Comment: @countermode I respectfully disagree.  This is neither a critique of the OP's question, nor a request for clarification.  It is a suggested resolution, in direct response to the OP's "can you point me to right direction?".

Comment: _see if this solves the problem_ is not a proper answer. If you look around on SE (anywhere) and check out high voted answers you'll notice the difference.

Comment: Hi simon,

I already tried (before posting) without success.

Comment: `df -h;df -i` will show if a partion is full or inodes .

Comment: @Bahamut I've updated the question with the output of the commands

Comment: Wrong Idea from me.  but this `E: busybox or busybox-static, version 1:1.22.0-17~ or later, is required but not installed` could be the Problem.

Comment: @Bahamut tried it